# Concatenar um valor SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Tenho um trigger que atualiza uma determinada tabela de matéria prima, porém ele substitui a quantidade existente e eu necessito que ele concatene o novo valor com o valor existente, alguém poderia me ajuda a como fazer isto?

```
create trigger trg_atualizaEstmatprim after update on ped_pedidos
for each row
begin
declare vQntP int(11) default 0;
declare vNomeMP varchar(100);
if(new.ped_status = 'PEDIDO EM PRODUÇÃO') THEN
-- UPDATE est_estoque SET;
    select (ped_quantidade * prod_mat_prim_gasta) as total,  prod_nome_matprim  into vQntP, vNomeMP 
    from ped_pedidos pe inner join
    prod_produto p on p.prod_codigo = pe.pro_produto_pro_id where ped_codigo = old.ped_codigo;
    if(vQntP>0)then
        update est_matprim set est_quantidade = vQntP where est_matprim_mat_materiaprima = vNomeMP;
    end if;
END IF;
end
```

Como podem ver ele dá um update substituindo o valor e eu gostaria de concatena-lo.

Comment: Especificamente em que parte está ocorrendo isso?

Comment: update est_matprim set est_quantidade = vQntP where est_matprim_mat_materiaprima = vNomeMP;

Desculpe a bagunça ali, não consegui ajustar no bloquete de codigo, mas seria neste update que eu gostaria de concatenar o vQntP em est_quantidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema, é que você está setando o valor de `est_quantidade` para o valor de `vQntP`, para fazer uma junção das duas, você deve fazer uma soma, desta maneira:

```
update est_matprim set est_quantidade = est_quantidade + vQntP where est_matprim_mat_materiaprima = vNomeMP;
```